How can I change the hover effect of antd modal button?
How can I change the hover effect of antd modal button? I'm trying to change the bg color of the hover and I try okButtonProps but it is not working!!
<Modal           
    open={open}
    onOk={handleOk}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
    cancelButtonProps={{
        style: { border: "1px solid red", color: "red" },
    }}
    okButtonProps={{
        style: {
            color: "#84cc16",
            border: "1px solid #84cc16",
       },
    }}
    okText={"Creat"}
    className=" p-0 bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden border-r-8 border-lime-500"
   >
       <MyComponent />
   </Modal>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
